# Sum of all rows in a column divided by the sum of that column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to know the sum of every row in a column divided by the total of that column and expressed as a percentage.

I did a new row for total as
df5.loc['Total'] = pd.Series(df5['Bounce Value'].sum(), index = ['Bounce Value'])

[I want it like the last column I currently have only the first3 columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7m4.png)

Comment: you mean sum / total number of items ?   because sum / total = 1, so that does not make sense....

Answer (score -1):

Multiple column by `sum`, then divide by `100` and round:

```
df5['Percentage'] = df5['Total of row'].div(df5['Total of row'].sum()).mul(100).round()
```